# What is the sum of this series? Geometric like series which seems like a generating function of some sorts.

Tags: calculus

$1+(\frac{1}2+\frac14)+(\frac12+\frac14)(\frac12+\frac18)+...$

I think it should sum to $e$ although I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: what is the next term or the general term?

Comment: $(\frac12+\frac14)(\frac12+\frac18)(\frac12+\frac{1}{16})$

Comment: So it is $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty\prod_{n=1}^m\left(\frac12+\frac1{2^{n+1}}\right)$$

Comment: @Sam According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+product+of+(1%2F2+%2B+1%2F2%5E(n%2B1))+from+n%3D1+to+m+from+m+to+infinity), the sum does not converge to $e$, but rather $1.76846$ approximately.

Comment: @TobyMak You should add $1$ to that calculation because it should be from $m=0$ i.e the first term is missing so $2.76846$

Comment: @kingW3 Well $e$ is approximately $2.718$, so that number definitely does not converge to $e$.

Comment: @TobyMak The lower bound for the terms is $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}\cdots=2$, so your WA approximation is in error.

Comment: When the sum is expressed as $1 + 1/2(1 + 1/2^{1})+ 1/2(1 + 1/2^{1} + 1/2^{2}) \cdots$, I think it could be related to the [q-Pochammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol).

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I can see that you're right - when $n=1$ the first term is $1/2 + 1/4$.

Comment: Wait, now that there are two $1$s at the beginning, this sum is at least $3$. @Sam

Comment: Oh I was told I was missing a 1

Comment: No, the missing $1$ was in the calculation Toby did, not in your formula. @Sam